# jQuery, remove certain chunks of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible, using jQuery (Or anything else), to remove certain bits of text from an element but leave the rest intact?

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that compiles all my tweets into WP posts but the post titles are automatically saved using the full text body of the tweet. For example;

`@username http://t.co/XXXXXXXX #hashtag`

I want to be able to remove the hyperlink and also the `#hashtag`

The hashtag will always be the same (Ie; it will always be `#hashtag`), but the hyperlink will change with every post. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: Could you post the bit of the plugin that creates this output?

Comment: the safest wat to remove text from a parent text is regular expression. for php its preg_replace().

Comment: @VolkanUlukut Using regex is the _unsafest_ way.

Comment: @BlackSheep What makes you say that? If you format your regex well, you can manipulate any text with pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Things could be harder or easier depending on whether the username, link and hashtag are always in the same position of the tweet or not. But I might suggest splitting the tweet string on ' ' and looping to construct a string without words that begin with '@', 'http://t.co', and '#'.

It would be easier with a full example because you may not want to remove all the handles, usernames, and hashtags. But I do suspect there is some uniformity in the format you may want to exploit.

Example:

```
   var words = $(el).text().split(' ');
   var cleaned = [];
   for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
         if (!(words[i].indexOf('@') === 1)) { // ... etc for other characters
             cleaned.push(words[i]);
         }
   }
   var cleaned_string = cleaned.join(' ');
```

Comment: they are always in the same order. Username, link, hashtag

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Link:](http://jsfiddle.net/gFg3f/1/)

```
var test = "@username http://t.co/XXXXXXXX #hashtag";
var matchindex = test.indexOf("#");
alert(matchindex);   // Tells you at what index the hashtag starts
var res = test.split("#");
alert(res[0]); // Gives you rest of the string without hastag
```

You can do something like this, to get the string without hashtag.You'll have to get the whole text as string into a variable first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove the url and the hastags, for example:
To remove the http part:

```
fullTweet.replace(/http:\/\/.+?\s/g, "");
```

The regular expression means `http://` followed by any number of characters until a space (use non-eager, i.e. +?, meaning it will stop at the first space)

To remove the hashtag

```
fullTweet.replace(/#.+?(\s|$)/g, "");
```

Here it's a # followed by any character until a space or end of string

[**Here's a complete example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/FFA9C/)

[Good reference for javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).